# Hive external table from avro files

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, avro, hortonworks-data-platform

Is it possible to create an external table on Hive 1.2 from an avro file without specifying the schema and make Hive extract it from data ?

I've found [this solution](http://community.hortonworks.com/answers/182840/view.html) but I'm wondering if Hive can extract the schema itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hive cannot extract the schema from the data. In order to read the data from the avro files in HDFS using a Hive query, Hive requires a schema.

So the solution you have found in the correct way of creating external table by taking the schema out of the file using "avro-tools". This way, the schema and the data resides in HDFS and referred from there by Hive.

Hope this helps!